# Display values from different month side by side?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to display data according to month side by side.

Below are the records in the table:

```
|Student ID| Type   | Date      | Amount($)
|00000001  | Foods  |01/01/2009 | 10
|00000001  | Foods  |01/02/2009 | 20
|00000002  | Drinks |01/01/2009 | 10
|00000003  | Snacks |01/02/2009 | 10
|00000003  | Drinks |01/02/2009 | 10
```

The expected results are like below:

```
|Student ID| Type   | Jan | Feb
|00000001  | Foods  | 10  | 20
|00000002  | Drinks | 10  | 0
|00000003  | Snacks | 0   | 10
|00000003  | Drinks | 0   | 10
```

The amount of type Foods for Student ID is displayed according to the month.

I tried to achieve the expected results by using CASE statement like below but it can't achieve like what is expected.

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID
  , TYPE
  , CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE)=1 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 AS JAN
  , CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE)=2 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 AS FEB
FROM CANTEEN_SPENT
```

But the results are like below

```
|Student ID| Type   | Jan | Feb
|00000001  | Foods  | 10  | 0
|00000001  | Foods  | 0   | 20
|00000002  | Drinks | 10  | 0
|00000003  | Snacks | 0   | 10
|00000003  | Drinks | 0   | 10
```

The data for Student ID 00000001 should be merged together as shown in the expected example.

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID
  , TYPE
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE) = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS JAN
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE) = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) AS FEB
FROM CANTEEN_SPENT
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID, TYPE
ORDER BY STUDENT_ID
```